# Get top users rank position depends on max count with join query

Tags: mysql

Depends on highest count i want to get the rank for each user.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 serial_number, `tbl_users`.`user_id`, 
`tbl_users`.`first_name`,
`tbl_users`.`last_name`,
 COUNT(`tbl_qa_questions`.`question_id`) AS qs_count 
FROM `tbl_qa_questions`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_users` 
ON `tbl_qa_questions`.`user_id` = `tbl_users`.`user_id` 
, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
WHERE 1 AND DATE(`tbl_qa_questions`.`post_date`) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-19' 
AND `tbl_qa_questions`.`status` = 1  
GROUP BY `tbl_qa_questions`.`user_id`
ORDER BY qs_count DESC  LIMIT 5
```

It is showing result

```
serial_number   user_id     first_name  last_name   qs_count
10              47          Sourav      Sen         26
11              32          Alan        Donald      15
9               587         Abraham     Harrison    2
8               586         Thomas      Broad       2
6               13          Sumanta     Sen         2
```

But it should:

```
serial_number   user_id     first_name  last_name   qs_count
1               47          Sourav      Sen         26
2               32          Alan        Donald      15
3               587         Abraham     Harrison    2
4               586         Thomas      Broad       2
5               13          Sumanta     Sen         2
.
.
.
29              14          xyz         Sen         2
30              15          abc         Sen         2
31              16          cdf         Sen         2
```

i.e. serial number for each row should be 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the numbering in an outer query, nesting your aggregation. The problem is that the variable gets incremented *before* `GROUP BY` kicks in, so you get a bit random results. It's actually always the case when using something in SELECT that is not in GROUP BY, specific to MySQL (other DBs just give you error).

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 serial_number, aa.* from (

sELECT
`tbl_users`.`first_name`,
`tbl_users`.`last_name`,
 COUNT(`tbl_qa_questions`.`question_id`) AS qs_count 
FROM `tbl_qa_questions`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_users` 
ON `tbl_qa_questions`.`user_id` = `tbl_users`.`user_id` 
, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
WHERE 1 AND DATE(`tbl_qa_questions`.`post_date`) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-19' 
AND `tbl_qa_questions`.`status` = 1  
GROUP BY `tbl_qa_questions`.`user_id`
ORDER BY qs_count DESC  LIMIT 5
) aa
```

Comment: may be some syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from ( SELECT `tbl_users`.`first_name`, `tbl_users`.`last_name`, COUNT(`tbl_q' at line 1 Can you please check again?

Comment: inside query runs successfully but when putting in outer query it generates an error..

Comment: ptrk, can u please check?

Comment: sorry forgot the mandatory alias for the nested one - edited the answer, please test

Comment: Another thing: in the top, i want top 5 user name but then depends on logged in user i will show previous, current and later user status. how can it be possible?

Comment: if you do not understand i will post another question for this. at top it will show rank of 1,2,3,4,5 rows  but after that if current users position is 30 then it will show the rank of 29,30 and 31 rows.

Comment: i updated the question. see the answer format. logged in user id is 15. and his rank is 30. so 29, 30 and 31 will show then. how it is possible.